# AngularJs TemplateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directive and I want to dynamic templateurl with attr.

For example;
I want to send attr with deviceEmpty tag. If this tag not null, use this tag. If this tag use static url.

AngularJs

```
directive('deviceEmpty', [function (scope) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl:'prototype.html',
                    link: function (scope) {
                        scope.value = 1;


                    }

                };
            }]).
            directive('screen', [function ($scope) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    templateUrl:function(elem,attrs) {
                        return  attrs.templateUrl || 'device_screens/{{homePageValue}}.html'|| 'device_screens/splash.html'

                    },
                    link:function(scope){
                    }


                };
            }]);
```

index.html

```
<device-Empty alternative-Home-Page="homePageAlternative-1"></device-Empty>
```

prototype.html

```
<screen template-url="device_screens/splash.html"  ng-switch-when="1"></screen>
<screen template-url="device_screens/samsung-screen-1.html"  ng-switch-when="2"></screen>
```

Comment: What is `homePageValue` and what is the issue?

Comment: I forgot it. scope:{homePageValue:'@alternativeHomePage'}